# VB6 label.caption property not changing

Tags: vb6

I have a label that the caption property does not change when written to.
The label caption stays with the text condition on program start.
The BackColor changes properly.

```
    txtBlower.LinkTopic = strTopic 'get F/A Blower Status
    txtBlower.LinkItem = "N7:12"
    txtBlower.LinkMode = 1

If txtBlower.Text = "1" Then
            lblBlower.BackColor = vbGreen
            lblBlower.Caption = "BLOWER ON"
        End If
        
        If txtBlower.Text = "0" Then
            lblBlower.BackColor = vbRed
            lblBlower.Caption = "BLOWER OFF"
        End If
```

The following is also in the program and works just fine.

```
txtWinter.LinkTopic = strTopic 'get Winter bit
    txtWinter.LinkItem = "N7:19"
    txtWinter.LinkMode = 1
    
    If txtWinter.Text = "1" Then
        lblWinter.BackColor = vbBlue
        lblWinter.Caption = "      WINTER"
        Else:
            lblWinter.BackColor = vbYellow
            lblWinter.Caption = "      SUMMER"
    End If
```

I can't find any differences in the properties of the text boxes or the labels.

Comment: If you set breakpoints on the lines which set the label values, are they hit? Does that code really execute?

Comment: `Else:` is a bit weird

Comment: Are there other places in code where the caption gets set?

Comment: @StayOnTarget the posted code was not executing. The actual changes to the label properties were being triggered by a Sub txtBlower_Change(). I wrote this program years ago, and forgot it was there. Thank you!

Comment: @Brian you were correct. Thank you! See comment to StayOnTarget